# Code Igniter - Unable to load requested file after redirect

Tags: codeigniter, debugging, redirect, controller

I am VERY new to codeigniter so please excuse me if this is a n00bish sort of question...

I have a controller called dashboard.php:

```
class Dashboard extends CI_Controller 
{
function __construct()
    {
    parent::__construct();
    }

function index()
    {
    if($this->session->userdata('logged_in'))
        {
        $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
        $data['username'] = $session_data['username'];

        $this->load->view('site_header');
        $this->load->view('dashboard'); 
        $this->load->view('site_footer');
        }
    else
        {
        //If no session, redirect to login page
        echo 'hello there';
        //redirect('main', 'refresh');
        }
    }

function logout()
    {
    $this->session->unset_userdata('logged_in');
    session_destroy();
    redirect('home', 'refresh');
    }

}

 ?>
```

**This page loads fine when i access it via localhost/sitename/dashboard.**

HOWEVER i am having issues trying to redirect to this controller from another controller of mine.  The controller that is calling the redirect is verifyLogin.php (in same directory level)

```
class VerifyLogin extends CI_Controller 
{

function __construct()
    {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('user','',TRUE);
    }

function index()
    {
    //This method will have the credentials validation
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|xss_clean|callback_check_database');

    if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
        //Field validation failed.  User redirected welcome page
        redirect('');
        }
   else
        {
        //Go to private area
        redirect('dashboard', 'index');
        }
    }

 function check_database($password)
    {
    //Field validation succeeded.  Validate against database
    $username = $this->input->post('username');

    //query the database
    $result = $this->user->login($username, $password);

    if($result)
        {
        $sess_array = array();
        foreach($result as $row)
            {

            $sess_array = array(
                'id' => $row->ID,
                'username' => $row->username,
                'stay_logged' => true
                );

            $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $sess_array);
            }
        return TRUE;
        }
   else
        {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('check_database', 'Invalid username or password');
        return false;
        }
    }
}

?>
```

When the redirect() is called i get an error - Unable to load the requested file: dashboard.php

After this error, i can no longer access localhost/sitename/dashboard (i just get that same error).

Some advice would be amazing right now as well as a way of debugging this for future problems.

Cheers!

Comment: do u have dashboard.php in your views folder?

Comment: No Amit, both dashboard.php and verifyLogin.php are in the controller directory.

Comment: What exactly your base_url? May be redirected url is wrong.

Comment: create dashboard.php in ur views, create with jus some dummy content

Comment: Base URL http://localhost/sitename/

Comment: But he said: "This page loads fine when i access it via localhost/sitename/dashboard." I guess dashboard.php file exist in view folder?

Comment: @AmitHorakeri: I am sure it isn't trying to redirect to a view (if that's what you're trying to tell me).  I know this because localhost/sitename/dashboard DOES work, the issue is just trying to get the redirect to work.

Comment: Before loading any view, u shud make sure that they exists in ur views folder, I here mean site_header.php,dashboard.php,site_footer.php, should be present in views folder

Comment: Try: return redirect(base_url('dashboard'));

Comment: if u can then try sending ur code to me to my email... I'll rectify n send it back to u .

Comment: Why does this have anything to do with view files?  Doesn't the redirect() function look in the controllers?

Comment: When you delete "$this->load->view('dashboard');" of line, get error again?

Comment: @Bora: You are 100% correct!  Why doesn't the error give extra info e.g. trying to load a view that doesn't exist?  Add an answer into the thread below and i'll mark yours as correct.

Comment: "Unable to load the requested file" is mean "trying to load a view that doesn't exist" ;))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to load a view that doesn't exist. Load dashboard.php to your view folder. I hope it works ;))

Comment: Thanks for that.  Would have been helpful to get an error message saying the view didn't exist!

Answer (score 2):

Use this pattern to redirect

```
redirect("controllername","function name");
```

or

```
redirect(base_url().'index.php/controller/function');
```

Answer (score 0):

By looking at you problem, I think this should help you out use this:

```
redirect(site_url().'dashboard', 'index');
```

Comment: No luck with that, same result :(

Comment: I think ur control is going within this if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
        //Field validation failed.  User redirected welcome page
        redirect('');
        }
SO its giving error I guess, because the redirect there is empty.

Answer (score 0):

try this one in verifylogin controller

```
redirect('Dashboard', 'refresh');
```

Let me know the result

Comment: when you redirect from verifylogin controller to Dashboard controller,your view are loading or not??

Comment: try to redirect with caps "D" like my answer.sometimes it causes a problem.